# How to predict labels for new data (test set) by the PartitionedEnsemble model in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, classification, cross-validation, ensemble-learning

I trained a ensemble model (RUSBoost) for a binary classification problem by the function **fitensemble()** in Matlab 2014a. The training by this function is performed 10-fold cross-validation through the input parameter "kfold" of the function **fitensemble()**.

However, the output model trained by this function cannot be used to predict the labels of new data if I use the **predict(model, Xtest)**. I checked the Matlab documents, which says we can use **kfoldPredict()** function to evaluate the trained model. But I did not find any input of the new data through this function. Also, I found the structure of the trained model with cross-validation is different from that model without cross-validation. So, **could anyone please advise me how to use the model, which is trained with cross-validation, to predict labels of new data?** Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`kfoldPredict()` needs a `RegressionPartitionedModel` or `ClassificationPartitionedEnsemble` object as input. This already contains the models and data for kfold cross validation.
The `RegressionPartitionedModel` object has a field `Trained`, in which the trained learners that are used for cross validation are stored.
You can take any of these learners and use it like `predict(learner, Xdata)`.

Edit:

If k is too large, it is possible that there is too little meaningful data in one or more iteration, so the model for that iteration is less accurate. 
There are no general rules for k, but `k=10` like in the MATLAB default is a good starting point to play around with it.
Maybe this is also interesting for you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27730/choice-of-k-in-k-fold-cross-validation

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question. Does any of these models in the field **Trained** have the same classification performance (ability) as the rest models in this field? That is, can I pick up any of the models from the field **Trained**?

Comment: No, the performance is not necessarily the same. This depends on your data and your choice of k in the kfold cross validation.

Comment: Could you please explain more details about how the **k** and data affects the results? Larger **k** and more data are better? Thanks!

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? Do you have any more question? If you consider my answers helpful I'd be happy if you accept my answer with the green checkmark :)